# How to change django manage.py default shell

Tags: python, django, shell, anaconda, ipython

I've just installed Anaconda and what's annoying that after executing:

```
python manage.py shell
```

The IPython shell is used. I'd like to change it back to default Python distribution. I'm using Visual Studio Code and already changed it interpreter to default python 3.6. Moreover the

```
python
```

command runs normal python distribution, and the problem exists both in Visual Studio and normal cmd terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Django 1.10+:

```
python manage.py shell --interface python
```

Django < 1.10:

```
python manage.py shell --plain
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you have used shell_plus.

`install django-extensions`, then use `python manage.py shell_plus`

shell plus is a very great tool.

you can use shell / shell_plus to have a plain interface

```
python manage.py shell_plus --plain
```

Note:- its not recommended to use django-extension in prod versions. But i'm sure you would love shell_plus, as this would reduce the headache of importing all models.

Comment: I know this answer, it's just that I'd prefere to use original shell. At least to know how to change between original, anaconda, and shell-plus shells.